# Extracting all files from a initrd cpio archive. How Do I?

Tags: boot, grub2, initrd

I have a initrd that i would like to extract the contents of. lsinitramfs displays a few directories including kernel, var, lib, usr.

But when i  `cat initrd.img | cpio -id`, only the kernel directory is extracted. Everything else isn't.

When i `cpio -ctv < initrd.img`, cpio returns `premature end of file`.

How do i inspect this initrd?

Comment: Have you seen https://askubuntu.com/a/1094855 ?